# In Pika or RabbitMQ, How do I check if any consumers are currently consuming?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I would like to check if a *Consumer/Worker* is present to consume a *Message* I am about to send.

If there isn't any *Worker*, I would start some workers (both consumers and publishers are on a single machine) and then go about publishing *Messages*.

If there is a function like `connection.check_if_has_consumers`, I would implement it somewhat like this -

```
import pika
import workers

# code for publishing to worker queue
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

# if there are no consumers running (would be nice to have such a function)
if not connection.check_if_has_consumers(queue="worker_queue", exchange=""):
    # start the workers in other processes, using python's `multiprocessing`
    workers.start_workers()

# now, publish with no fear of your queues getting filled up
channel.queue_declare(queue="worker_queue", auto_delete=False, durable=True)
channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="worker_queue", body="rockin",
                            properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
connection.close()
```

But I am unable to find any function with `check_if_has_consumers` functionality in *pika*.

Is there some way of accomplishing this, using *pika*? or maybe, by *talking* to ***The Rabbit*** directly?

I am not completely sure, but I really think *RabbitMQ* would be aware of the number of consumers subscribed to different queues, since it does dispatch *messages* to them and accepts *acks*

I just got started with *RabbitMQ* 3 hours ago... any help is welcome...

here is the **workers.py** code I wrote, if its any help....

```
import multiprocessing
import pika


def start_workers(num=3):
    """start workers as non-daemon processes"""
    for i in xrange(num):    
        process = WorkerProcess()
        process.start()


class WorkerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    worker process that waits infinitly for task msgs and calls
    the `callback` whenever it gets a msg
    """
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.stop_working = multiprocessing.Event()

    def run(self):
        """
        worker method, open a channel through a pika connection and
        start consuming
        """
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                              pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
                     )
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='worker_queue', auto_delete=False,
                                                    durable=True)

        # don't give work to one worker guy until he's finished
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='worker_queue')

        # do what `channel.start_consuming()` does but with stopping signal
        while len(channel._consumers) and not self.stop_working.is_set():
            channel.transport.connection.process_data_events()

        channel.stop_consuming()
        connection.close()
        return 0

    def signal_exit(self):
        """exit when finished with current loop"""
        self.stop_working.set()

    def exit(self):
        """exit worker, blocks until worker is finished and dead"""
        self.signal_exit()
        while self.is_alive(): # checking `is_alive()` on zombies kills them
            time.sleep(1)

    def kill(self):
        """kill now! should not use this, might create problems"""
        self.terminate()
        self.join()


def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
    """pika basic consume callback"""
    print 'GOT:', body
    # do some heavy lifting here
    result = save_to_database(body)
    print 'DONE:', result
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

**EDIT:**

I have to move forward so here is a workaround that I am going to take, unless a better approach comes along,

So, *RabbitMQ* has these [HTTP management apis](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v2_8_7/priv/www/api/index.html), they work after you have turned on the [management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and at middle of HTTP apis page there is

> /api/connections - A list of all open connections.
>
> /api/connections/name - An individual connection. DELETEing it will close the connection.

So, if I connect my *Workers* and my *Produces* both by different *Connection* names / users, I'll be able to check if the *Worker Connection* is open... (there might be issues when worker dies...)

will be waiting for a better solution...

**EDIT:**

just found this in the rabbitmq docs, but this would be hacky to do in python:

```
shobhit@oracle:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl -p vhostname list_queues name consumers
Listing queues ...
worker_queue    0
...done.
```

so i could do something like,

```
subprocess.call("echo password|sudo -S rabbitmqctl -p vhostname list_queues name consumers | grep 'worker_queue'")
```

hacky... still hope pika has some python function to do this...

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just looking into this as well.  After reading through the source and docs I came across the following in channel.py:

```
@property
def consumer_tags(self):
    """Property method that returns a list of currently active consumers

    :rtype: list

    """
    return self._consumers.keys()
```

My own testing was successful.  I used the following where my channel object is self._channel:

```
if len(self._channel.consumer_tags) == 0:
        LOGGER.info("Nobody is listening.  I'll come back in a couple of minutes.")
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found this on accident looking for a different issue, but one thing that may help you is on the Basic_Publish function, there is a parameter "Immediate" which is defaulted to False.

One idea you could do is to set the Immediate Flag to True, which will require it to be consumed by a consumer immediately, instead of sitting in a queue. If a worker is not available to consume the message, it will kick back an error, telling you to start another worker.

Depending on the throughput of your system, this would either be spawning a lot of extra workers, or spawning workers to replace dead workers. For the former issue you can write an admin-like system that simply tracks workers via a control queue, where you can tell a "Runner" like process to kill processes of workers that are now no longer necessary.

Comment: Just a note, if you try to do this in Kombu, it will not work because despite being an argument to `Producer.publish`, `immediate` is not supported: https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/latest/reference/kombu.html#kombu.Producer.publish