# What to do when Celery broker is down?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Celery server with a RabbitMQ broker. I use it to run background tasks in my Django project.

In one of my views a signal is triggered which then calls a celery task like this:

```
create_something.delay(pk)
```

The task is defined like this:

```
@task
def create_something(donation_pk):
    # do something
```

Everything works great, but:

If RabbitMQ is down when I am calling the task no error is thrown during the create_something.delay(pk) call. But the view throws this error:

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

(The stack trace is kind of useless, I think this is because of the signals used)

The question now is: How can I prevent this error? Is there a possibility to perform retries of the create_something.delay(pk) when the broker is down?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Celery tasks has a `.run()` method, which will execute the task as it were part of the normal code flow.

```
create_something.run(pk)
```

You could catch the exception and execute `.run()` if needed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but my create_something.delay(pk) does not thow any exception...

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037121/in-pika-or-rabbitmq-how-do-i-check-if-any-consumers-are-currently-consuming

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to perform retries of the create_something.delay(pk) when the broker is down?

The exception thrown when you call the `.delay()` method and you cannot connect can be caught just like any other exception:

```
try:
    foo.delay()
except <whatever exception is actually thrown>:
    # recover
```

You could build a loop around this to retry but you should take care not to keep the request up for very long. For instance, if it takes a whole second for your connectivity problem to get resolved, you don't want to hold up the request for a whole second. An option here may be to abort quickly but use the logging infrastructure so that an email is sent to the site administrators. A retry loop would be the *last* thing I'd do once I've identified what causes the connectivity issue and I have determined it cannot be helped. In most cases, it *can* be helped, and the retry loop is really a bandaid solution.

> How can I prevent this error?

By making sure your broker does not go down. To get a more precise answer, you'd have to give more diagnostic information in your question.

By the way, Celery has a notion of [retrying tasks](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) but that's for when the task is *already* known to the broker. It does not apply to the case where you cannot contact the broker.