# How to get the list of hosts listening on a particular Que in Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, celeryd

In my project I have two ques. I would like to know list of all the workers listening to a que.
(need a pythonic way of doing this. Celery is running on a different machine and I want the details on other machine.)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're using rabbitmq as a broker you can do this:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_consumers
```

To check a specific queue:

```
lpiner@host:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_consumers -p production |  grep queue1
queue1 <rabbit@host1-rabbitmq.2.15149.130>     None5   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host1-rabbitmq.2.15256.130>     None4   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host1-rabbitmq.2.21562.130>     None4   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host1-rabbitmq.2.21644.130>     None4   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host1-rabbitmq.2.6500.135>      None5   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host2-rabbitmq.2.4028.137>      None10  true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host2-rabbitmq.2.4083.137>      None10  true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host2-rabbitmq.2.4463.137>      None9   true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host2-rabbitmq.2.4497.137>      None10  true    0       []
queue1 <rabbit@host2-rabbitmq.2.6508.137>      None5   true    0       []
```

You can also use the celery flower UI which is pretty cool.
https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Im looking for a python way of doing this and running my celery on a different machine than the one where want the details.

Comment: It looks like you can do this with the Pika library, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848105/5339255. I don't think celery has an easy way to do this.